# What does it mean when 99th percentile has decreased and 50th percentile has increased for a service?

Tags: java, performance, statistics, soa, latency

I am trying to compare the performance of two services. One of then runs on an older codebase and the other is a newer implementation. I have tried to plot numbers based on instrumentation and I am comparing the average (50th percentile) and max (99th percentile) numbers for a sampling period of 30 seconds.

The observation is that for the newer service: the 50th percentile has increased by 40% (increased from 0.05ms to 0.07ms) while the 99th percentile has gone down from 17ms to 11ms.

I have tracked the behavior for one whole day.

My question is:

**What does this tell about the performance of the newer codebase?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says that your `mean` is increased and your `variance` is decreased. Your newer code performs a bit worse on an average but the worst case times  taken is better than your pervious codebase.

Comment: @ReservoirSampling latencies don't follow a normal distribution or anything like it.  See my answer below where the 99.9% confidence interval doesn't even cover the 50th percentile.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did not mean to say that it follows normal distribution, I was just trying to explain the average and worst case  and yes I agree that  I have used `mean` and `variance` in an incorrect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> average (50th percentile)

The 50th percentile is the median or typical latency.  The average is the total of all the latencies divided by the number and is usually greater than the median. If your average is 20% higher your median you are doing well.  It can be many times, even 10x your typical.

> and max (99th percentile)

Actually the 99th percentile is like the minimum I look at.  Here is an example from JMH.

```
Result "rwire8bit":
  344.069 ±(99.9%) 0.029 ns/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (279.000, 344.069, 8224.000), stdev = 24.468
  CI (99.9%): [344.039, 344.098] (assumes normal distribution)
  Samples, N = 7496517
        mean =    344.069 ±(99.9%) 0.029 ns/op
         min =    279.000 ns/op
  p( 0.0000) =    279.000 ns/op
  p(50.0000) =    342.000 ns/op
  p(90.0000) =    362.000 ns/op
  p(95.0000) =    364.000 ns/op
  p(99.0000) =    371.000 ns/op
  p(99.9000) =    379.000 ns/op
  p(99.9900) =    520.696 ns/op
  p(99.9990) =   2648.557 ns/op
  p(99.9999) =   5904.056 ns/op
         max =   8224.000 ns/op
```

This is the time to encode and decode a message with 6 fields.  The point being that the 99th percentile should be just the beginning when performance tuning, you have the 99.9th, 99.99th, 99.999th, 99.9999th and the maximum is the worst sample ever. Note: this test ran for around 200 million samples.

> What does this tell about the performance of the newer codebase?

This is a common situation when a system is designed to improve the consistency of it's performance.

You are willing to trade off a little on your typical latency so that your worst latencies are better.

> The observation is that for the newer service: the 50th percentile has increased by 40% (increased from 0.05ms to 0.07ms) while the 99th percentile has gone down from 17ms to 11ms.

As a rule of thumb, if your 99th percentile should be no more than 4x your typical which suggests to me that with optimisation you should be able to reduce your 99th to 0.28 ms rather than 11 ms, but it depends on the variety of operations you are testing.

Comment: From 99th percentile latency from my program jumps from 0.02us to 5 to 25us. I'm using JLBH instead of JMH with over 10K warm up iterations. Is there a way/tool to find out the reason of the runs that produce outliars?

Comment: @Abidi It probably should be built into JLBH but you can monitor the thread from another one and take stack traces when the delay is long

Comment: Even if JLBH takes stack-trace of all outliars, it wouldn't tell why it took significantly long especially when the same piece of code is being executed? Seems like, it's a profilers' job to show what code (JVM or System calls) was being executed. Even a sampling profiler could miss this, right? Do we need an instrumentation profiler?

Comment: @Abidi if you want to know what it is spending it's time in total, that is what a profiler does. If you want to know what is it doing when it is taking longer than expected, you need to only sample when this happens.

Comment: Lets say, my code that adds an integer to a LInkedList is in a for loop, after every run I check how long it took and if it's longer than what I'm expecting I print stack-trace? How would that help in finding out why this particular run took long because isn't it going to print the same stack-trace as last one? For example, OS decided to do something else, or a system call was executing?

Comment: @Abidi You need another thread to take the stack trace while the thread you are monitoring is busy. When you start a critical block, put the System.nanoTime() into an AtomicLong. You can set it to Long.MAX_VALUE when you are done. In the monitoring thread, it the critical section has been executing for too long e.g. 20 micros, you take a stack trace of the thread being monitored and log it.

Answer (score 0):

The newer codebase is in general slightly slower (increase from 0.05ms to 0.07ms) but doesnt have as much high peaks (11ms down from 17ms).

If thats a good thing is dependent on the use case or the requirement.

For example, if the service has to respond within 15ms at all times, this is a good improvement. If the service has to answer within 0.1ms its not a good improvement, because the service wont answer in time more often and if the service did not, it's regardless if it took 10ms or 15ms.

What you have to keep in mind is the precision of measurement. In such a small timespan (0.05ms or 50ns) it is much more likley that there are flaws in the measuring method than in a timespan like 10ms.